# Retrieve multiple documents matching multiple search criteria

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to work out if it's possible to do a $match/$elemMatch where 0 or more documents match an array of object input conditions. I'm trying to avoid querying for each item individually.

An $or won't work because the number of lookup items is not fixed, unless it's the case that the only way to do this is dynamically create the $or query...

e.g.

```
db.tshirts.insertMany([
    {_id:0, code: "123", label: "Yellow T-Shirt", style: [{ size: "SM", fabric: "cotton"},{ size: "MD", fabric: "bamboo"}]},
    {_id:1, code: "456", label: "Blue T-Shirt", style: [{ size: "MD", fabric: "bamboo"},{ size: "LG", fabric: "cotton"}]},
    {_id:2, code: "789", label: "Red T-Shirt", style: [{ size: "SM", fabric: "cotton"},{ size: "LG", fabric: "cotton"}]},
    {_id:3, code: "321", label: "Green T-Shirt", style: [{ size: "LG", fabric: "bamboo"},{ size: "LG", fabric: "bamboo"}]}
])


//Looking for n or more documents matching this criteria
var lookup = [
    {
        code: "123",
        style: {
            size: "SM"
        }
    },
    {
        code: "789",
        style: {
            size: "MD"
        }
    },
    {
        code: "321",
        style: {
            size: "LG"
        }
    },
]

db.tshirts.find/aggregate(/* use lookup values for search */)

//desired output
[
    {_id:0, code: "123", label: "Yellow T-Shirt", style: [{ size: "SM", fabric: "cotton"},{ size: "MD", fabric: "bamboo"}]},
    {_id:3, code: "321", label: "Green T-Shirt", style: [{ size: "LG", fabric: "bamboo"},{ size: "LG", fabric: "bamboo"}]}
]
```

Comment: why not dynamically build the query?

Comment: I'm interested to know if there's some other way of doing it.

Comment: nothig comes to mind but if ur lookup had fields like `[{'style.size':'LG',code:....},...]` then u could directly pass it in the or condition https://mongoplayground.net/p/RgPcZCWU3ZE

Comment: btw building the query isnt that much? just a `map`

Comment: @cmgchess I'd be keen to see you map solution as an answer if you have time. I'm pretty new to MongoDB so any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: From map I meant js array map to transfom the lookup array. Assuming you are using JavaScript

Comment: `db.collection.aggregate([{$match: {$or: lookup.map(e => ({'style.size':e.style.size,code:e.code})) }}])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done using an aggregation pipeline with a `$filter` step:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$match: {
      $expr: {$gt: [
          {$size: {$filter: {
                input: lookup,
                cond: {$and: [
                    {$eq: ["$$this.code", "$code"]},
                    {$in: ["$$this.style.size", "$style.size"]}
                ]}
          }}},
          0
      ]}
  }}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PeDHZUI5sQ7)